# Prevent line break caused by \part in article class

Tags: line-breaking, parts

I'm trying to prevent the line break caused by the `\part` command. In a second step, I'd also like to get rid of the word 'Part' in the output. Hence, what I'd like to have is:

I ABC

But I'm stuck with:

Part I

ABC

So far, using`\renewcommand{\partname}{}` at least drops the word 'Part'. But I'm stuck with the rest. Any help is much appreciated!

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    \part{ABC}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you not simply use `\section` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the `\@part` command. Using `etoolbox` to patch it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\Large\bfseries\partname\nobreakspace\thepart\par\nobreak}
  {%
    \huge % Same font size as the part title
    \bfseries % Bold face
    \thepart % Part number
    \nobreakspace % Space
  }
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\part{ABC}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

produces:

> [image]